# Eclipse+CDT for Android NDK on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: android, linux

Did anybody try to use Eclipse+CDT on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit for Android NDK development?
I did it on Ubuntu 10 and everything worked fine but now I'm starting on a new machine and I was wondering whether everything would work on Ubuntu 12.10 too. On Internet I didn't find anything saying that I can and anything saying that I can't.
I tried it and it is slower than on 10.04 on the same hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on exactly this configuration and it works perfectly.